# Restar o sumar mes a una fecha

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts

Estoy trabajando con Highcharts y estoy mostrando información de mi base de datos de la siguiente forma:

```
      data: [<?php  
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "[Date.UTC(".date('y,m,d', strtotime($row['fecha_emision']))."),".$row['total_dia']."],"; 

        }
        } 
    ?>
```

Pero el problema es que mi script considera el primer mes como 0. Así que cuando  mi base de datos se muestra la siguiente fecha:

[Date.UTC(2016, 06, 6), 14]

Considera esta fecha como **6 de Julio** cuando en realidad debería ser el **6 de Junio**.

La solución es de la siguiente forma:

```
    data: [<?php  
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        //RESTAMOS UN MES LA FECHA, PUES JAVASCRIPT CONSIDERA EL PRIMER MES 0;
       $fecha_emision=$row['fecha_emision'];
    echo "[Date.UTC(".date('y,m,d', strtotime("-1 month", strtotime($fecha_emision)))."),".$row['total_dia']."],"; 

    }
    } 
?>

    ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

seria algo mas o menos como esto

```
  $actual = strtotime($row['fecha_emision']);
  $mesmenos = date("Y,m,d", strtotime("-1 month", $actual));
```

esto le resta 1 mes a la fecha en la que tu estas asignando actual, si necesitas agregar 1 mes mas `+1 month`